# /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, order-summary

Can anyone explain what does /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information it mean?

I want to hide Cash payment option. By using jquery I am able to hide cash payment option but when page get refreshed through order summary page, then Cash payment option get displayed.

Comment: does somebody know how to override this valdation.php file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information** Is the rest api which map to **PaymentInformationManagementInterface**. Here **mine** means you are logged in customer.

Open **vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/webapi.xml** here actually map.

When you click **Place Order** button, magento call **vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php**

**savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder**

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __($e->getMessage()),
            $e
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->getLogger()->critical($e);
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the valuable information. Can u tell me,  Is it possible to hide Cash payment option on onclick of Check payment option?

Comment: Yes, you need to do with js stuff

Comment: using jquery I am able to hide cash payment option but when page get refreshed through order summary page, then Cash payment option get displayed

Comment: as a complement https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-checkout-application-order-placing/

Comment: What is the solution ? I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Agreements are validated before saving payment information.
I have researched and found this

vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/Checkout/Plugin/Validation.php

```
public function beforeSavePaymentInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    if ($this->isAgreementEnabled() && !$quote->getIsMultiShipping()) {
        $this->validateAgreements($paymentMethod);
    }
}
```