# required fields are required but not displayed on shipping address

Tags: checkout, shipping, magento2.3.3

Im using `magento 2.3.3`, when I try to submit chekout order, it does not show some fields and it gives me:

Please check the shipping address information. "`firstname`" is required. Enter and try again. "`lastname`" is required. Enter and try again. "`city`" is required. Enter and try again.

please help

Comment: please check the your console error in shipping page ??

Comment: can you tell me where please?

Comment: in your console showing any js error ??

Comment: it gives me /rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Please check root_dir/var/report/api folder if exist or root_dir/var/exception.log file you will get the reason probably.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202179/rest-default-v1-carts-mine-payment-information#comment280201_202180