# How do you accept terms and conditions via API?

Tags: magento2, api

I attempted to place an order via `/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information` and got the following response:

```
    "message": "The order wasn't placed. First, agree to the terms and conditions, then try placing your order again."
}
```

How do I accept terms via API?

Comment: please refer this link : - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202179/rest-default-v1-carts-mine-payment-information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please request this sample :

```
{
            "set_paid": false,
            "paymentMethod": {
                "method": "string",
                "extension_attributes": {"agreement_ids": ["string"]}
            },
            " billing_address": {
                "region": "string",
                "region_id": int,
                "country_id": "string",
                "street": [
                    "string"
                ],
                "postcode": "int",
                "city": "string",
                "firstname": "string",
                "lastname": "string",
                "email": "string",
                "telephone": "string",
                "same_as_billing": 1    
            }
        }
```

You can use the below API to get all list of conditions

```
[Base Url]/rest/V1/carts/licence
```

**Also, you can refer to this docs for more information**

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/checkoutPaymentInformationManagementV1/checkoutPaymentInformationManagementV1SavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrderPost

Comment: Where do you get the agreement ID?  Can you pull the agreements via API?

Comment: I believe that is the correct URL to get the agreements, however, it is not accessible to the customer on my install.  Still, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I had faced the same issue when Terms and Conditions were enabled from admin end.
This issue/answer is for those when using Magento 2 Api and at the time of placing order you will get error message `"{"message":"The order wasn't placed. First, agree to the terms and conditions, then try placing your order again."}"`

To resolve this you need to pass agreement_ids in payment method to place order:

```
 "paymentMethod": {
                "method": "cashondelivery",
                "extension_attributes": {"agreement_ids": ["1"]}
            },
```

Here agreement_ids can be found from backend admin panel Admin ->Configuration->Terms and Conditons
id will be mentioned over there.